# Entity Framework: delete list of child objects from parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, parent-child, delete-row

I basically have a pretty simple setup of a one-to-many parent-child relationships. E.g.:

```
public class Parent
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
   public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This is configured using FluentValidation as:

```
public ChildConfiguration()
{
   ToTable("children");
   HasKey(c => c.Id);

   Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("id");

   HasRequired(c => c.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children);
}
```

I now have an API that provides the list of children for a parent, but I don't want to add the list of children to the existing list every time. Instead I want to delete all existing children to replace them with the list of new ones.

I tried doing so by fetching the parent, clearing the current list of children and adding the new ones.

```
var parent = await _repository.GetById(parentId);
parent.Children.Clear();
foreach (var child in children)
{
    parent.Children.Add(child);
}
```

This does not work, as it throws an exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

As I understood this is because it's trying to remove the link between the two entities rather than actually deleting it from the database.

A solution is to directly access the Children in the DbContext and do a RemoveRange as:

```
DbContext.Children.RemoveRange(children);
```

But I don't want to expose my Children entity directly on the context. Instead I always want to go through the Parent. So I could create a method in the repository like:

```
var parent = DbContext.Parents.Find(parentId);
foreach (var child in parent.Children.ToList())
{
   parent.Remove(child);
}
```

But this is throwing the same exception and I don't understand why as I think I am explicitly telling EF to remove the child from the parent.

Is there a way to remove the children from the DB without accessing them directly on the DbContext?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to loop over `parent.Children` and set their `children.Parent = null`?

Comment: That's throwing the same exception.

Comment: Have you tried `parent.Children.RemoveRange(parent.Children)` instead of clearing the collection? This seems like it would cause some sort of recursive error, but it might work.

Comment: Actually, I think any way you try to remove it from the parent collection will just be a relationship change and you HAVE to remove it directly from the context.

Comment: You may be able to do something when your context is created, like adding a function to delete objects that are marked to be "removed", like this post talks about here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsimmons/2010/02/05/cascade-delete-and-1-to-1-or-1-to-0-1-relationships/ that way you can remove objects from a child collection and then when you call save changes it will delete them before saving changes. He's talking about cascade delete, but it might work for you.

Answer (score -1):

**Guid** is a struct and struct is non-nullable type like primitive types. 
eg : **int**, **double**, **bool**, etc...

You will be able to delete the children of a given parent with your following code

```
var parent = await _repository.GetById(parentId);
parent.Children.Clear();
foreach (var child in children)
{
     parent.Children.Add(child);
}
```

by declaring your **Guid ParentId** property in you Child class **Nullable** like this **Nullable<*Guid*>**.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I guess it would work indeed. But then I am basically saying that my child has an optional parent which is not true. A child cannot exist without its parent.

Comment: I actually just tried it and it's not working either. It throws an exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. Which is the FK I have from my child.parentId that links to my parent.Id.